# 2015 BMW 750Li Xdrive

Tags: tires

The right rear tire (passenger side) is almost completely bald whereas the opposite tire has normal treadwear (plenty of tread, approx 7/32).  Any idea what could cause this disparity?

Comment: Are they they exactly the same tires, and were they installed from new at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I had this a couple of months ago, for me it was the inner edge of the rear tire.

This was down to one suspension arm having a collapsed bush, once sorted it was fine. Just difficult to spot without measuring...